# Проблема с PySide2

Tags: python, discord, pyside2

Пишу приложение с GUI для написания личных сообщений через через бота. Есть 2 проблемы:

1. При получении сообщения вызывается `on_message(message)`, в этой функции берётся контент сообщения и добавляется в textBrowser. При получении сообщения он выдаёт ошибку `RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit) already deleted.`
   Уже не знаю что делать
2. Не знаю как сделать отправку сообщений: есть функция, вызываемая по клику кнопки, там по введённому в специальное поле id находится юзер и бот должен отправить сообщение этому юзеру, но он не может запустить функцию `send_msg(user,msgg)`
   , нет идей.

Вот код:

```
import sys          
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from code import Ui_Dialog
import discord as ds
import asyncio
client = ds.Client()
ui = None
mmsg = None
class Bot:
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        global ui
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.show()
        ui.pushButton_bot_login.clicked.connect(b_actions.noa)
        ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(b_actions.give_me_data)
        ui.clr_txt.clicked.connect(b_actions.clr_txt)
        app.exec_()
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        global ui
        print(ui.lineEdit.text())
        if ui.lineEdit.text() == message.author.id:
            ui.textBrowser.setText(ui.textBrowser.toPlainText() + str(message.author) + ": " + str(message.content) + "\n")
class b_actions:
    global ui
    global mmsg
    def give_me_data():
        id = ui.lineEdit.text()
        msgg = ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        ui.textBrowser.setText(ui.textBrowser.toPlainText() + f'{client.user}' + ": " + msgg + "\n")
        user = client.get_user(int(id))
    def noa():
        ui.textBrowser.setText(ui.textBrowser.toPlainText() + "Зашёл как: " + f'{client.user}' + "\n")
    def clr_txt():
        ui.textBrowser.setText("")
    str(message.content) + "\n")
    async def send_msg(user,msgg):
        await user.send(msgg)
client.run("токен")
```

Comment: либо добавьте во все методы классов первый аргумент self, либо удалите строки, содержащие слово class, потому что смысла в классах, так как вы их испольдуете, нет никакого

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Убрал все классы, всё та же ошибка(

Comment: Теперь добавил во все методы класса `b_actions` self - ничего не изменилось

Comment: ошибка означает, что ваш qlineedit уже удален сборщиком мусора.

Comment: Что? Извините, я не понял, можно поподробнее?

Comment: Переменная, значение которой вы пытаетесь получить, уже удалена сборщиком мусора python. Области видимости. Скоуп и все такое. Проверьте где это происходит

Comment: метод async def on_ready() вызывается? если нет, то не создается ваш ui и т. д.

Comment: Но я пробовал через `print(dir(ui))`, он стабильно выдавал все те кнопки, поля и т.д, что есть у меня в гуи. Или этого не достаточно?

Comment: Метод `on_ready` вызывается 100%, так как этот метод вызывается при старте бота

Comment: а вот эта строка print(ui.lineEdit.text()) что выдает?

Comment: Она-то ошибку и делает, но если её убрать, то он будет ругаться на следующий if

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, как думаете, не лучше ли было бота с его асинхронными методами отправить в отдельный поток (`QThread`), а GUI оставить в главном потоке? Связь же между GUI и ботом сделать через сигналы

Comment: Он кстати не ругается на другие методы, использующие переменную ui. Только на `on_message(message`)

Comment: @dil9red лисичка поседеет, если мы сейчас про потоки начнем рассказывать ) Асинхрон и так должен работать

Comment: а вот так print(ui.lineEdit), что выводит в вашем on_message?

Comment: сейчас попробую...

Comment: Та же ошибка(`RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit) already deleted.
`)

Comment: вот этой строки class Bot:  точно не надо

Comment: Я уже убирал все классы, всё работало будто код не трогали.

Comment: Спасибо за правку вопроса, я накосячил чуть-чуть

Comment: попробуйте убрать global ui  в on_message https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1544

Comment: Тогда какой смысл? мне нужно чтоб он брал и того `ui` из определённого поля брал `id`, сравнивал с `id`, полученного сообщения, в случае успеха, чтоб он просто редактировал `textBrowser`. Если я уберу `global ui`, то смысле в этом не будет

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228, `global` нужен только когда вы присваиваете значение глобальной переменной (`ui = ...`), если его не будет в том месте просто будет создана новая переменная с тем же именем, а глобальная не будет изменена

Comment: Так ну, тогда ж я и не смогу взять поле с той глобальной переменной

Comment: или смогу.....?

Comment: Попробовал - та же ошибка....

Comment: Кажется понял. Вы создаете Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog() и он умирает сразу после выхода из метода on_ready, а вместе с ним умирает и ваш интерфейс. Сейчас предложу в ответе другую структуру приложения

Comment: Ну кстати может быть, буду благодарен

Comment: @gil9red вы были абсолютно правы! Все работает через поток и совсем не сложно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл данной структуры в том, чтобы отделить асинхронные методы дискорда от графического интерфейса пользователя, а клиент дискорда запускать в отдельном потоке (господин @gil9red чертовски прав! Лучи добра ему!):

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread
from code import Ui_Dialog
import discord as ds
import asyncio

client = ds.Client()
ui = None

# Класс потока, в котором будет бежать наш дискорд-клиент
class ClientThread(QThread):
    # Главный метод потока
    # Запускается вызовом метода start (смотри в самом низу)   
    def run(self):
        # Протестировал на реальном клиенте
        client.run("NzEwMzg2...")            

class b_actions:
    @staticmethod
    def give_me_data():
        id = ui.lineEdit.text()
        msgg = ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        ui.textBrowser.setText(ui.textBrowser.toPlainText() + f'{client.user}' + ": " + msgg + "\n")
        user = client.get_user(int(id))

    @staticmethod
    def noa():
        ui.textBrowser.setText(ui.textBrowser.toPlainText() + "Зашёл как: " + f'{client.user}' + "\n")

    @staticmethod
    def clr_txt():
        ui.textBrowser.setText("")
#        str(message.content) + "\n")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global ui
    print(ui.lineEdit.text())
    if ui.lineEdit.text() == message.author.id:
        ui.textBrowser.setText(ui.textBrowser.toPlainText() + str(message.author) + ": " + str(message.content) + "\n")

async def send_msg(user,msgg):
    await user.send(msgg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()

    ui.pushButton_bot_login.clicked.connect(b_actions.noa)
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(b_actions.give_me_data)
    ui.clr_txt.clicked.connect(b_actions.clr_txt)

    # Создаем и запускаем поток с дискорд-клиентом
    th = ClientThread()        
    th.start()

    app.exec_()
```

Архитектуру можно улучшить - отделить операции с GUI от операций с дискорд-клиентом

Comment: AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'show'
в
ui.show()

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 Ui_Dialog это окно, поэтому замените этот класс на тот, который у вас отвечает за GUI

Comment: сейчас попробую....

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 смысл в том чтобы создать объект ui и поместить в него весь ваш графический интерфейс.

Comment: ничего не понимаю...(

Comment: Блин, случилось то, чего я боялся: `client.run()` заставляет приложение зависнуть: то есть оно открывается, не прорисовывает ничего и зависает, будто грузится. Это случалось в самом начале разработки - поэтому-то рисование гуя я поместил в `on_ready()`

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228, поэтому я в комментарии под вопросом и писал, что лучше в `QThread` поместить бота discord, т.к. `client.run` имеет цикл, что заблокирует поток с GUI: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L622

Comment: Ну да, тогда придётся изучать QThread... Спасибо в любом случае

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 обновил ответ. Ничего сложного в потоке для дискорда нет. Копируйте и запускайте, все проверил (У вас только GUI-окно другое)

Comment: та же ошибка, что и в первый раз.....`AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'show'` в `ui.show()`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, нужно повторить код из вопроса с `ui.setupUi(Dialog)`, т.к. `Ui_Dialog` не является виджетом, а просто классом (от object), который в `setupUi` меняет свойства виджета `Dialog` и размещает на нем виджеты из `ui`, обычно через компоновщики

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 исправил ответ

Comment: Подождите секундочку...

Comment: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x21c1caabb10), parent's thread is QThread(0x21c1caaa0f0), current thread is ClientThread(0x21c1cf14e20)
Segmentation fault
` никогда с таким не сталкивался...

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 ну да, нельзя создать дочерний виджет для родителя из другого потока. Но, как бы, а где вы это делаете?

Comment: делал в QtDesigner'е (и я не знаю как создать дочерний виджет для радотеля из другого потока, так как новичок полный)

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 так делать нельзя. GUI должен жить в главном потоке приложения (дочерние виджеты их родители, окна и так далее), а все остальное можно размещать в других потоках. Тот код, который я указал, рабочий - я его потестил на своем аккаунте дискорда

Comment: Блин, тогда в чём же может быть проблема...? Ладно, в любом случае спасибо, сейчас обозначу ответ как правильный

Comment: @Jlucu4ka228 Теряюсь в догадках - проверьте отступы у методов. В классе ClientThread всего один метод run, в котором вызван client.run() и все, остальное в главном окне приложения. Кроме того, в асинхронных методах гуишные виджеты только вызываются, но ничего нового не создается

Comment: Да вроде бы нормально... Вы табами ставили отступы? Просто у  меня они почему-то пробелами